# Почему выходит ошибка в классе?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Component {
    constructor(options) {
        this.#el.document.querySelector(selector);
        this.#el.style.width = this.#el.style.height = options.size + "px";
        this.#el.style.background = options.color;
    }
}

let component = new Component({
    selector: 'box1',
    size: 100,
    color: 'red'
})
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: reference to undeclared private field or method #el` -- а что конкретно из этого непонятно? Или какоего поведения Вы ожидали и почему?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы в конструкторе пытаетесь обратиться к полю, которого нет

Не знаю точно, что вы хотите сделать, но можно вот так

```js
class Component {
    #el = document.createElement('div'); // создали приватное поле
    
    constructor(options) {
        this.#el.querySelector(options.selector);
        this.#el.style.width = this.#el.style.height = options.size + "px";
        this.#el.style.background = options.color;
        
        console.info(this.#el);
    }
}

let component = new Component({
    selector: 'box1',
    size: 100,
    color: 'red'
});
```